# Implement bit operations only by ADD, SUB, MUL and DIV instructions

Tags: assembly, bitwise-operators

I am writing a compiler -- just for fun and to improve my skills. I'd like to implement a subset of C language. The problem is: I'm compiling to the assembler of theoretical 16-bit RISC processor called Sextium II (we used to teach assembler on it on our University).

The processor uses only 16 commands, and none of them is a bit operation. I would like to implement C bit operators -- and afterwards half-precision floats -- but I have no idea how to implement bit operations using only `ADD`, `SUB`, `MUL` and `DIV` instructions. Bit-shift is quite easy, it is just multiplication or division by `2^n`, where `n` is the shift length. But what about `AND`, `OR`, `NOT` or `XOR`?

**EDIT**
To be clear: processor computes only in 16-bit signed U2 arithmetics.

Comment: It's going to be slow, but x AND 1 is x MOD 2, using a loop and shifting each time you can construct a 16-bit AND. 1-bit x OR y is (x AND 1) || (y AND 1) (I'm assuming you already have this implemented), again a loop will give you a 16-bit version. Similar for XOR and NOT. I'm sure this can be done in a smarter way, but this could work as a fallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you look at a bitwise truth table for add for example:

```
a b  c r
0 0  0 0
0 1  0 1
1 0  0 1
1 1  1 0
```

a and b are the input operands r is the result c is the carry out.

From a bitwise perspective an add is an xor.  But to use this as a generic xor you would need to perform 16 add operations, one for each bit plus all the work that surrounds masking one operand and extracting the result bit.

```
a b  c r
0 1  0 1
1 1  1 0
```

Focusing in on the add again but with the b operand always a one, you get a not function.  Here again, would need masking and shifting.

of course you dont have masking and shifting do you?

A multiplier will shift left, times 2 is a shift of 1 times 4 a shift of 2 and so on. Likewise a divide is a shift right.  Divide by 4 is a shift of 2, divide by 8 is a shift of 3 and so on.  You could mask individual bits this way, divide by 8 to shift right 3 then multiply by 0x8000 to shift left 15, then divide by 0x1000.  Would that be the same as anding with a 0x0008?

If that works then you could say multiply by 0x100 then divide by 0x100 and have that be the same as anding with 0xFF00.

is it a signed multiply (and divide) or unsigned? or do you have both?

Comment: All operations are made on 16-bit signed U2 arithmetics.

Comment: That may change things with the multiply and divide when sign bits get involved.  For example an unsigned multiply of 0x8000 * 0x7FFF is 0x3FFF8000, where a signed multiply of 0x8000 * 0x7FFF is 0xC0008000.  You may not have a 16bit * 16bit = 32 bit result, so these two might look the same (and actually do what I was hoping they would do), but dividing 0x8000 by 0x1000 gives 0x0008 unsigned and 0xFFF8 signed.

Comment: Thank you. I thought there will be some hacks to make things faster, but apparently there isn't. I'm going to accept your answer.

Comment: It sounds like that teaching computer needs a few more instructions, or perhaps there are some other instructions that would help that we dont know about.  For example a nor or a nand and some way to use immediates you can do any logical operation.

Comment: Nope, only 16 instructions, including NOP.